# Integration of Pusher and socket programming in android

Tags: android, cordova

i am implementing socket programming with pusher .but i don't know where to write ip address so that i can get data from server .
i am using this example
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-phonegap-android
can you please tell me where i write Ip s that i will get response.
(function($) {

```
  var CONFIG = {
    PUSHER: {
      APP_KEY: '49e26cb8e9dde3dfc009'
    }
  };

  Pusher.log = function(msg) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
      window.console.log(msg);
      $( '#debug_log' ).prepend( msg );
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {

    // Get device info
    var deviceInfo = 'Device Name: ' + device.name + '<br />' +
      'Device Cordova: ' + device.cordova + '<br />' +
      'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
      'Device UUID: ' + device.uuid + '<br />' +
      'Device Version: ' + device.version + '<br />';

    $('#deviceProperties').html(deviceInfo)

    // Connect
    var pusher = new Pusher("ws://192.168.1.3:8101/");// i am writting Here my ip but connection problem occur
    pusher.connection.bind('state_change', connectionStateChange);

    function connectionStateChange(state) {
      $('#connectionStatus').html(state.current);
    }

    // Subscribe
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', subscriptionSucceeded);

    function subscriptionSucceeded() {
      $('#subscriptionStatus').html('succeeded');
    }

    channel.bind('my-event', handleMyEvent);

    function handleMyEvent(data) {
      $('#debug_log').append('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    }

  }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question from my side, is there actually websocket server listening on specified host?

**Upd.:** Pusher is the hosted platform, so you cannot run it locally. If you like you can use open-source alternative like Slanger (https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger). Please refer to it's documentation where it is described how to setup Pusher client accordingly.

Comment: yes ..I am doing socket programming having this url with port  ws://192.168.1.3:8101/

Comment: If you will check Pusher's docs https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js you will see that the first param in constructor is actually an API_KEY. Pusher is actually a hosted API, so it connects to a predefined host.

Comment: I do not know what's you backend. If you do not want to have hosted solution, I would recomment to take a look on http://vert-x.github.io/. It has SockJS backend implementation (WebSocket with fallback protocols) and nice EventBus bridging feature which allows to seamlessly share the same bus with backend and frontend processes.

Comment: Please check here is my serverhttp://help.airbrake.io/discussions/github-issues/1039-file?unresolve=true

Comment: Create folder on D directory of name(casepad).then inside  again maike new folder NewExcCasePad .Then run this command LexSrvPC.exe /Demo:"LexSrvPC.raw".I need to show this data.I am hitting to my local server .But i am not getting data

Comment: if you are able do (or get some data ) please let me know i am frustrated from this.

Comment: Sorry, I work on Mac and can't run your server. Pusher is the hosted platform, so you cannot run it locally. If you like to use open-source alternative like Slanger (https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) please refer to it's documentation.

Comment: can you solve this problem ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425152/unusual-behavior-display-while-showing-pop-up-screen-in-jquery-mobile/17440747?noredirect=1#17440747